# Webview in programmatically created RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I need the following xml to be made in code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#00000000"
            >
            <android.webkit.WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/adview"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ></android.webkit.WebView>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="x" android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/hide_popup_button" android:background="#00000000" 
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/adview" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I use the code below but I get a `Force close`:

```
RelativeLayout popwindow=new RelativeLayout(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
        popwindow.setLayoutParams(rl);
        WebView w= new WebView(this);
        w.setId(0X100);
        w.setScrollContainer(false);
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)w.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        Button b=new Button(this);
        b.setId(0X101);
        b.setText("X");
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        b.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsbut = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)b.getLayoutParams();
        paramsbut.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        paramsbut.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,w.getId() );
        popwindow.addView(w,params);
        popwindow.addView(b,paramsbut);
        setContentView(popwindow);
```

I need suggestions on how to make that xml layout through java code.

Comment: try LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); w.setLayoutParams(param); instead of android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)w.getLayoutParams();

Comment: " gets force close" post log cat as well..

Comment: If I edit to improve your question, please don't revert the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should post any exception you get in your question. See if this helps:

```
    RelativeLayout popwindow=new RelativeLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams rl= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
    popwindow.setLayoutParams(rl);
    WebView w= new WebView(this);
    w.setId(0X100);
    w.setScrollContainer(false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 50);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    w.setLayoutParams(params);
    Button b=new Button(this);
    b.setId(0X101);
    b.setText("X");
    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ReloativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    bparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    bparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, w.getId());
    b.setLayoutParams(bparams);        
    popwindow.addView(w);
    popwindow.addView(b);
    setContentView(popwindow);
```

Custom component holding the `WebView` and the `Button`:

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

        private WebView mWebView;
        private Button mButton;

        public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mWebView = new WebView(context);
            mWebView.setId(0X100);
            mWebView.setScrollContainer(false);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 50);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            mWebView.setLayoutParams(params);
            mButton = new Button(context);
            mButton.setId(0X101);
            mButton.setText("X");
            mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            bparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            bparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, mWebView.getId());
            mButton.setLayoutParams(bparams);
            addView(mWebView);
            addView(mButton);
        }

        public WebView getTheWebView() {
            return mWebView;
        }

        public Button getTheButton() {
            return mButton;
        }

    }
```

To use that component:

```
CustomRelativeLayout popWindow = new CustomRelativeLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams rl= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
setContentView(popWindow);
// get a reference to the WebView and the Button
WebView w = popWindow.getTheWebView();
Button b = popWindow.getTheButton();
```

Comment: is it possible to create it in another class extends layout and refer it in our main class

Comment: @Shalini Do you want to create a custom component that will hold your WebView + button and then use that component in your activity?

Comment: yes. i use the above code in another class extends that layout and use button and webview in mainclass

Comment: Thanks for spending me your time. i will try it now :)

Comment: I get the button and webview through your code. But now how can i get the whole layout and refer it in main class. ex:TransparentPanel tp=(TransparentPanel) findViewById(thatlayourhere?);

Comment: @Shalini Place the custom component in your layout like this `<com.your.package.CustomRelativeLayout android:id="@+id/the_id" //other attributes />` and then reference it in code with `findViewById`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13146/discussion-between-shalini-and-luksprog)

Comment: how to close CustomRelativeLayout when click on X button

Comment: how to set radious in webview. programaticaley